# Problems with .addClass().removeClass()

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I spent a few hours last night trying to figure out what was going wrong here, but was unsuccessful.
I have a div that when clicked will expand and create a close button that will return the div to its original state. I am doing this by adding and remove classes. The issue I am having is that when the original div (.talent) is clicked it does change to fill the containing div. However when the button (.btn) is clicked the div does not return to its original state.

JS -

```
$(".talents .talent").click(function(){
  if ($(this).hasClass("talent")) {
    $(this)
      .removeClass("talent")
      .addClass("tree")
      .append("<div class=\"close btn\">X</div>");

    $(".tree .btn").click(function(){
      console.debug("WORKING!?!?!?");
      $(".tree").addClass("talent");
      $(".tree").removeClass("tree");
      $(".talents .talent").show();
      $(this).remove();
    });
    $(".talents .talent").hide();
  }
});
```

CSS -

```
.talents{
  border:1px solid white;
  border-radius:10px;
  overflow:hidden;

  height:165px;

  margin:10px;
}

.talents .talent{
  text-align:center;
  font-size:2.4em;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 3px solid white;
  border-radius: 15px;
  margin: 5px 7px 5px 7px;
}

.tree{
  position:relative;

  width:100%;
  height:100%;
}
```

Comment: How about some HTML markup, too, so we can test this?

Comment: can you provide a jsfiddle for it?

Comment: Yea, Sorry. One moment and I will have the HTML.

Comment: `if ($(this).hasClass("talent"))` will always evaluate to `true` in your code as you are selecting all the elements with the class `talent` that are descendants of elements with the class `talents`

Comment: Here is a replication: http://jsfiddle.net/gamesfreke/nf8fU/

Comment: The if statement is to prevent the click vent from firing after the change, but before it is reverted to the smaller object.

Comment: @gamesfreke.. Check the fiddle in my post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Events are bound **to the elements** in question, not to a specific class. You need to `delegate the events in such cases` as the classes are being added dynamically.

In your case if you put a `debug point` you can see the issue properly. Th event bubbles up to the parent which at that time is `.talent` . So first it works as expected when clicked on `close`, but then fires the click event on `.talent` again which places the `tree` class on that element again. Event delegation should solve this problem.

```
$(".talents").on('click', ".talent", function () {
    $(this)
        .removeClass("talent")
        .addClass("tree")
        .append("<div class=\"close btn\">X</div>");
    $(".talents .talent").hide();
});


$(".talents").on('click', ".tree .btn", function () {
    console.debug("WORKING!?!?!?");
    $(".tree").addClass("talent");
    $(".tree").removeClass("tree");
    $(".talents .talent").show();
    $(this).remove();
});
```

**[Check Fixed Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/NXPZE/)**

Answer (score 3):

```
$(".talents .talent").click(function(){
  if ($(this).hasClass("talent")) {
```

THE ABOVE CODE WILL ALWAYS EVALUATE TO TRUE

if you want this to work better, whatever element has the class of talent should also have another class, and work similiar like this(I would say use .tree as .other_class but can't be 100% certain without seeing html):

```
$(".talents .other_class").click(function(){
  if ($(this).hasClass("talent")) {
```

Also, it would be a better practice to keep the btn click handler outside the first click handler.

Answer (score 0):

Haven't tested but another problem may be because the class `.tree` is appended dynamically. Also try using `on` like:

```
$(document).click('.tree .btn',function(){
     console.debug("WORKING!?!?!?");
     $(".tree").addClass("talent");
     $(".tree").removeClass("tree");
     $(".talents .talent").show();
     $(this).remove();
 });
```

Answer (score -2):

First remove the class and then try to add a class and see if it is working.

```
$(".tree").removeClass("tree");
$(".tree").addClass("talent");
```

Comment: waiting for your fiddle to test the above!

Comment: If the first line removes the tree class, how does the 2nd line work?

Comment: @Archer Was about to comment the same